# Android: Open/read or copy file in local network

Tags: java, android

completely newby in Android, coming from c# world..
I've written a little private app for android and that must not be available on play store and the like... 
the app is using JTDS to directly connect to local SQL Server to manage "inputs" from the device, and it works as expected :)

again, the app can not be updated via play store, but now I'd like to provide a feature to update it [occasionally it will :)]
so I'd like to verify on a local network share a text file containing the latest build available and, eventually, copying the "new" apk to android \Download directory...
but I still have to find a way to "read\connect" the the LAN's share...
I've seen other threads like
[How to use httpget in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938420/how-to-use-httpget-in-my-app?rq=1)
and basically my code follows [How to get file via HttpGet from pc in local network on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124420/how-to-get-file-via-httpget-from-pc-in-local-network-on-android)

but the code "fails" with 404 status code...
in the HttpGet(file) I've provided the LAN location of the file I need to read, like
String file = "http://192.168.x.xxx/NetworkShare/file2read.txt";

the share is on a Windows7 machine with readonly permissions and no authentication required... It's not a Windows Domain, it's just a WorkGroup so permissions troubles should be excluded...
I'm still checking with the emulator and not the physical devices...
the manifest already includes Internet permissions, WIFI_STATE, NETWORK_STATE
If helps, I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0

any hint or alternative?

### TIA

asql

Comment: I havent used HttpGet. But if i understand it correctly you will need to have a webserver running (something that understands Http Protocol, to 'serve' the file and make it available at a given url. For your needs you might try something like this : http://www.cnet.com/how-to/share-files-between-android-and-windows-with-es-file-explorer/

Good luck!

Comment: hi and thank you for your input... actually I'd like to not use a web service, but just directly go to the windows share and perform the read/copy IO operation... other suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do with HttpGet won't work with a Lan location because when you share a directory you are using SMB,CIFS or NFS protocol and it's impossible to access those files via HTTP. If you want to use HttpGet you must publish your files through a HTTP server.

I think there is no way to mount a drive programmatically in Android. It is possible with busybox but maybe you need to be root.

The best way to do what you want is getting the information from a webservice or maybe downloading your file from a ftp server.

Comment: Your general point about the difference between http vs. a network filesystem protocol is quite important and correct.  And you are right that you cannot literally mount a network filesystem from unprivileged 3rd party code.  However, it is possible to obtain data from a network fileserver without mounting it - in effect, you build code to implement the access into your app, and you collect the data in some internal format, rather than trying to make it appear as a file which you can open with file apis.  Of course once you have the data internally, you can write out a local copy as a file.

Comment: hi and thank you for your input. I understand http & ftp will have troubles becouse I'm not connecting to a "Server"
Having a look at jcifs, but no valuable documentation can be found
I do get jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC000009A
tried to provide authentication info like
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "user", "pwd");
but then I get
jcifs smbfile plain text passwords are disabled
and adding
jcifs.Config.setProperty("smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords", "false");
does not help
any other suggestion/example to connect to a Win7 share in a Windows WorkGroup?